# Oracle Server dropping sessions Frequently

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have an oracle server which is dropping Sessions (Connections) frequently, with just about 5 minutes idle time it is dropping the connection. Resource limit is not set on this server, and the IDLE_TIME for the User profile is set to unlimited, the strange thing is this happens even when we create a new instance, and that too behaves in the same way.

I am using Oracle 10g R2 on Windows 2000.

Comment: Think you should ask this question on ServerFault.com

Comment: What error(s) do you get on the client and on the server?  Do you see anything in the various logs on the database side?

Comment: On the Client side we see a "ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel" which is usually about network connections. I don't remember seeing much on server side, but then i am also not that efficient on at db servers.

Answer (score 1):

this could be caused by a firewall rule (kill idle connections after X minutes). You could check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83068/ora-03113-end-of-file-on-communication-channel-after-long-inactivity-in-asp-net) and ask your network administrator to check the firewall configuration.

Comment: This was happening to me in IDE's like Toad and not Asp.net. Also this is in an development network where there is no firewall.