# Django Oracle App gives ORA-03113 and ORA-03135

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have a Django app that connects to Oracle. Every 10 refreshes or so, regardless of what page, it gives an error. First time after restart an ORA-03113 and every subsequent errors ORA-03135.

I have checked to alert.log and listener.log on the database side and can't find anything about this session terminating in the log file.

I've edited site-packages/django/db/**init**.py and put an try/except around close_if_unusable_or_obsolete. The page does not give an error anymore, and in the logfile no ORA error but I still see the SIGPIPE error.

My guess : Django thinks there is still a connection and tries to close (close_if_unusable_or_obsolete) it but on the Oracle side the connection does not exist. The first ORA-03113 does not result in a record in the listener.log, so it seems it does not even reach the Database server. After the modification in the **init**.py the result page is correct. So the query for building up the page is successful. It seems to be a connection for administrative purposes of some kind.

I'm lost, does anyone have an idea how to find this error?

```
cx_oracle==5.1.3
Django==1.8.3
Oracle Client : instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0
Database version : 11.2.0.3.0
```

uwsgi_error.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
    signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__, environ=environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 189, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 64, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 403, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 198, in close
    self._close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 152, in _close
    return self.connection.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 152, in _close
    return self.connection.close()
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 10345
Session ID: 195 Serial number: 54225

[pid: 30|app: 0|req: 1/4] 123.123.123.123 () {46 vars in 1024 bytes} [Fri May 27 15:58:34 2016] GET /admin/ => generated 0 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
[pid: 28|app: 0|req: 4/5] 123.123.123.123 () {46 vars in 1024 bytes} [Fri May 27 15:58:38 2016] GET /admin/ => generated 31712 bytes in 291 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 251 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 28|app: 0|req: 5/6] 123.123.123.123 () {46 vars in 1024 bytes} [Fri May 27 15:58:39 2016] GET /admin/ => generated 31712 bytes in 276 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 251 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 28|app: 0|req: 6/7] 123.123.123.123 () {46 vars in 1024 bytes} [Fri May 27 15:58:40 2016] GET /admin/ => generated 31712 bytes in 288 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 251 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 30|app: 0|req: 2/8] 123.123.123.123 () {46 vars in 1024 bytes} [Fri May 27 15:58:40 2016] GET /admin/ => generated 31712 bytes in 608 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 251 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
Fri May 27 15:58:41 2016 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /admin/ (ip 131.180.77.1) !!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
    signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__, environ=environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 189, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 64, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 403, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 198, in close
    self._close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 152, in _close
    return self.connection.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 152, in _close
    return self.connection.close()
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ORA-03135: connection lost contact
Process ID: 10345
Session ID: 195 Serial number: 54225
```

SQL*Net trace file contains:

```
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:303] nioqsn: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqsn: exit
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqrc: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nsbasic_bsd: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nsbasic_bsd: tot=0, plen=13.
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nttfpwr: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nttfpwr: socket 29 had bytes written=13
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nttfpwr: exit
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nsbasic_bsd: packet dump
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nsbasic_bsd: 00 0D 00 00 06 00 00 00  |........|
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nsbasic_bsd: 00 00 03 0F 0F           |.....   |
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nsbasic_bsd: exit (0)
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nsbasic_brc: entry: oln/tot=0
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nttfprd: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] ntt2err: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] ntt2err: Read unexpected EOF ERROR on 29
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] ntt2err: exit
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nttfprd: exit
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nserror: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nserror: nsres: id=0, op=68, ns=12537, ns2=12560; nt[0]=507, nt[1]=0, nt[2]=0; ora[0]=0, ora[1]=0, ora[2]=0
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nsbasic_brc: exit: oln=0, dln=0, tot=0, rc=-1
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqer: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqer:  incoming err = 12151
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqce: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqce: exit
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqer:  returning err = 3113
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqer: exit
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqrc: exit
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqds: entry
(4043057216) [31-MAY-2016 15:18:51:304] nioqds:  disconnecting...
```

Incomming Error ORA-12151: TNS:received bad packet type from network layer

**EDIT Response to Titus**

```
SELECT PROFILE, LIMIT FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE RESOURCE_NAME = 'IDLE_TIME'; and: 
DEFAULT UNLIMITED

SELECT PROFILE FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME = 'DJANGO_USER';
DEFAULT
```

I don't use TNSNAMES.ORA or SQLNET.ORA

Comment: Perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83068/ora-03113-end-of-file-on-communication-channel-after-long-inactivity-in-asp-net helps

Comment: @trinchet Thank you. I have seen the link. There is no error on the service side. There is no firewall between appserver and dbserver. The connection _does_ work but now and then fails.

Comment: You are saying that you checked the alert.log for the database and do not see any errors from that time?  It wouldn't be an ORA-3113 in the alert log, it'd be something different.  Also, are you using TLS (Transport Layer Security, aka SSL)?

Comment: Can you post the output from this:
SELECT PROFILE, LIMIT FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE RESOURCE_NAME = 'IDLE_TIME';

and:
SELECT PROFILE FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME = DJANGO_USER;

Comment: Also, the contents of your SQLNET.ora and, if your using TNS, TNSNAMES.ora.

Comment: @TitusP Thanks for your response. This does not seem to be a timeout problem since it occurs right after starting the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the workaround that worked for me:

```py
# wsgi.py
from django.db import connection
from uwsgidecorators import postfork

@postfork
def reconnect_to_db():
    print "RECONNECT TO DB!"
    connection.connect()
```

For some reason, the uwsgi workers need to be manually connected `postfork`, or the first query of every worker would fail.