# Importing data into an Oracle table from a CSV file using SQL developer is terminating Connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm having a weird issue with my SQL developer. I'm importing data into one of the existing table(with no data in it) in oracle database(DEV Environment) from a CSV file using import option in Oracle SQL developer. My connection gets terminated automatically as soon as I start the import with the error shown in the screenshot. After clicking "yes" task gets cancelled and import is rolled back. Finally, it is automatically resetting my database connection. To know the issue, I converted it to .txt file and also with using previous files which I was able to import successfully before and tried to import it again but having same issue.

Appreciate insights on this issue!

[image]

[image]

Comment: share with us your data, also check your alert logs in the database for a clue as to why the connection is being terminated

Comment: Sorry, cannot share data but I have been importing it on a monthly basis. I have tried with CSV files that I previously able to import successfully and even they are failing now

Comment: w/o data, you're asking us to guess..have your import generate INSERT scripts instead of doing the actual work/import - run that, see where it breaks

Comment: I'm not asking to guess. I can't share enterprise data. It is not a source data issue, as I said I tried with files that I was able to import successfully before and even they are failing now. This time I tried running them using a different tool(Alteryx designer) which gave end of communication error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83068/ora-03113-end-of-file-on-communication-channel-after-long-inactivity-in-asp-net

Comment: my advice had an entire 2nd part...use the script option...and check the ALERT log, sounds like the db or listener is dropping your connections